# Dependent DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I want to make a dependency property whose value depend on other dependency property but still settable/writable. For example, ‘DateOfBirth’ is an independent [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx). Now I want to make another DependencyProperty with name YearOfBirth.  When DateOfBirth with Change it will Coerce the value of YearOfBirth property. i.e. d.[CoerceValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.coercevalue(v=vs.110).aspx)(YearOfBirthProperty).

But How can I make dependent dependency property (e.g. YearOfBirth) writeable/settable?

If I code using CLR Properties, it works fine but how can do by using Dependency Properties!

Comment: Take a look at [CoerceValueCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.coercevaluecallback(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static DependencyProperty DateofBirthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DateofBirth", typeof(DateTime), typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(DateofBirth_Changed)));

    public DateTime DateofBirth
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateofBirthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DateofBirthProperty, value); }
    }


    private static void DateofBirth_Changed(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        MainWindow thisClass = (MainWindow)o;
        thisClass.SetDateofBirth();
    }

    private void SetDateofBirth()
    {
        DOBYear = DateofBirth.Year;
    }

    public static DependencyProperty DOBYearProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DOBYear", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(DOBYear_Changed)));

    public int DOBYear
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(DOBYearProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DOBYearProperty, value); }
    }


    private static void DOBYear_Changed(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        MainWindow thisClass = (MainWindow)o;
        thisClass.SetDOBYear();
    }

    private void SetDOBYear()
    {
        //Put Instance DOBYear Property Changed code here
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; in this approach, we actually create two standalone properties that change each other when they change. On the other hand, I am looking a way in which YearOfBirth not store its value in RAM as it is calculated value but on demand it calculate form DateOfBirth. Obviously when user try to change YearOfBirth, it will update DateOfBirth.